# Essential JS 2 Grid: save/restore column order and width?

Tags: syncfusion

The use case is to a) allow the user to resize columns and reorder them, which the Grid can do, and then by user reset to what they had.

What I need: how do I a) read/set the column order and b) read/set the column widths? If there's a document with a description of grid column properties and methods, that's what I need. Or, if the column widths and order are stored elsewhere on the grid, the doc for that component.

thanks,

Hank

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, we have achieved the resetting of resize and reorder columns after we do both actions on Grid using getPersistData and setProperties methods. We have locally to store the Grid Properties using getPersistData(it is store feasible of resetting grid properties) method in load event of Grid and you can bind the locally stored grid properties to Grid using setProperties method when we reset the positions and width of the columns in the Grid. please refer to the Grid code example and sample for more information.

```
 [Index.cshtml]

<ejs-grid id="Grid" dataSource="ViewBag.dataSource" allowReordering="true" allowResizing="true" load="onLoad">
    <e-grid-columns>
   .   .   .   . 
    </e-grid-columns>
</ejs-grid>



<script>

    function onLoad() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("gridPorps", this.getPersistData());  //Store the intial renderting Grid properties in global variable
    }

    document.getElementById("resetprops").addEventListener("click", function () {        
        var grid = (document.getElementById("Grid") as any).ej2_instances[0];
        grid.setProperties(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("gridPorps")));  //Bind the stored Grid properties in the Grid 
    });
```

**Sample link:**  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/252153/ze/filter_core-120629378.zip

Else If you expect to reset the Grid columns positions and width after reorder and resizing the Grid columns. Please share your exact requirement to us it will help validate further.

Please get back to us, if you need further assistance.

Best,

Balaji S